# Showing independent, multiple ajax query results per row in a table AJAX,PHP

Tags: php, ajax, html-table

Objective:
To show a new, unique set of options in a drop-down box, for each row in the table, by using AJAX and PHP.

Details:
I have a table written in PHP, where, I create the rows of the table in for loop:

Code:

```
<table>
foreach ($mylist as $i)
{
<tr>
  <td>
       echo '<select name="product[]" onchange="showItems(this.value,'.$i.')" >';
       echo "<option value='APPLE'>APPLE</option>";
       echo "<option value='ORANGE'>ORANGE</option>";
       echo "<option value='PLUM'>PLUM</option>";
       echo '</select>';
  </td>
  <td>
       echo '<select name="sales[]" id="txtHint">';
       echo '</select>';
  </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

This creates a table that looks like this:

```
No.   Product                sales mode
---   -------                -------
 1    (Drop-down list here)  (drop-down list here)
 2    (Drop-down list here)  (drop-down list here)
```

There are `N` no. of table rows.

When user selects a particular option, say, "APPLE" from the drop-down list, in the `Product` column, for `row 1`,  then the corresponding `sales mode` column for the same `row 1` is updated with options using AJAX, relevant to the `APPLE` product selected in the first column.

That is, Based on option in `Product` column, the options in `sales mode` column will change.(And not vice-versa).

The problem I am facing is, whenever, I select a new different product,in the second row of the table, the first row's `sales mode` column also changes, based on the second row's `Product` selection.

In the first step:

```
No.  Product   sales mode
---  ----      ----------
 1   Apple     EXPRESS
 2   (Select)  (Select)
```

When I do this next[Choosing `Orange` option in the `product` column]:

```
No.  Product   sales mode
---  ----      ----------
 1   Apple     EXPRESS//This is the default option for Apple
 2   Orange    (select)
```

It becomes this:

```
No.  Product   sales mode
---  ----      ----------
 1   Apple     REGULAR//This is the default option for Orange 
 2   Orange    (select)
```

AJAX code:

```
function showItems(str,val)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str+"&val="+val,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

How do I achieve this? [Fairly new to AJAX]

Appreciate your help, suggestions. 
Let me know, if you need further information.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the pertinent html, but I don't see anything in your ajax code that differentiates which element gets updated.

Comment: The HTML code is rendered, the same as the PHP code shown in the first code section.

Comment: @askmish: The PHP `foreach` loop you have seems to be making a new `<select>` each time it loops. You certainly don't want that, right?

Comment: @aguyfromhere : The select  needs to be there for each and every list of items.

Comment: @askmish: OK. I normally do one `<select>` and many `<options>` but every programming situation is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your html you're setting the `id` of all of the sales mode dropdowns to `txtHint`. Aside from being invalid html, it's causing your ajax call back to always update the first element it finds with that id, which happens to be the one for Apple in your example. What you want to do is give each of them a unique id, and use that in your callback.

Comment: is right. Normally when you iterate over the data with `foreach` you put a dynamic id in the `<option>` like so: `<option id="<?php echo $id?>>`

Comment: Ah! Got it! I was missing this point. The code changes based on your inputs work now. Changed each select to represent a unique id.